# FFMPEG - Converting all images that are uploaded to MP4s

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, ffmpeg

I have created some FFMPEG codes to execute once an video has been loaded. I am still fairly new at this, so please give as much information as possible.

```
// ffmpeg Location
$ffmpeg = 'c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe';
$ffprobe = 'c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe';

// Video Filename Dir
$video0 = $caption->row()->vidFile;
// ex. output: upload/user/vid23.mov 

// Video Filename only
$video1 = explode('/',$video0);
$video2 = $video1[2];
// ex. output = vid23.mov;

// Remove Extensions
function extensions ($video2) 
{ 
     $filename = strtolower($video2); 
     $exts = explode(".", $video2); 
     $n = count($exts)-2; 
     $exts = $exts[$n]; 
     return $exts; 
 } 

     $ext2 = extensions($video2);
// ex. output = vid23;

     //Convert all files to Mp4s
     //exec("$ffmpeg -i $video0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy $ext2.mp4");
     exec("$ffmpeg -i $video0 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=-1:360 -qscale 7 -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 32 -ar 24000 $ext2.mp4");
```

Am I doing something incorrect? It works when I test it on my test location, but once I moved it into production useing **Codeigniter** Framework. It's not working (Well, correction, just this part is not working - My image thumbnail does what is needed)

Please help in anyway possible. Thanks!

**EDIT**

The main issue with the code is it will totally skip over the section and not execute at all. I didn't receive any error messages. Another issue is the file tends to codec error because of the moov data (bytes 0-32/33). I did do some reading, but since I'm not familiar with FFMPEG it is hard to read or understand.

Example site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/396883/how-to-simply-convert-video-files-i-e-mkv-to-mp4

I used that site as a base.

**ERROR LOG INFO**

Updated the FFMPEG exec script to the following

```
exec("$ffmpeg -i $video0 -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=-2:360 
-acodec libfdk_aac -ab 32k -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart 
-ar 24000 $ext2.mp4 2> log/error_log.txt");
```

The Error log printed out the following

```
ffmpeg version N-80101-gd970f7b Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
 configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads 
 --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig 
 --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass 
 --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype 
 --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug 
 --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus 
 --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy 
 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame 
 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis 
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 
 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg 
 --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
libavcodec     57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
libavformat    57. 37.100 / 57. 37.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 46.100 /  6. 46.100
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
upload/user/vid53.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "Not working" is not very descriptive. What exactly is the actual issue? Do you not get any error messages? Is the problem with your scripting or with the `ffmpeg` command? What about the `ffmpeg` console output/log? As for your ffmpeg command: `-qscale` is ignored by libx264 so remove that, use `-2` instead of `-1` in scale so the output is divisible by 2, `-ab 32` is using 32 bits/s, so add a "k", as in `-ab 32k`. Consider adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to ensure widely compatible chroma subsampling, and `-movflags +faststart` if the output is to be viewed via progressive download.

Comment: I will update the post. :)

Comment: Thanks @LordNeckbeard for your assistants. I will add these updates to see the new outcome. Is it possible for you to write out exactly how it should be written: `ffmpeg ...` or does it not matter which order it is placed?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I just tried your additional codes and this is what the log read - SEE ABOVE

Comment: How did you fix it? You can provide an answer to your own question.

Comment: I just deleted the "`-acodec libfdk_aac`" this codec isn't compiled in FFMPEG zip. All files are converted perfectly without any issues. @LordNeckbeard

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was just to remove the codec that I didnt have compile.

So I removed `-acodec libfdk_aac` and it works now.